# Dynamic user control change - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I'm developing an app in WPF and I need to change in runtime a content of a `ContentControl` depending than the user selected on `ComboBox`.

I have two UserControls and at my combo exists two itens, corresponding each one each.

First usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Validator.RespView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="167" d:DesignWidth="366" Name="Resp">
<Grid>
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ListBox Height="112" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,43,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" />
    <Calendar Height="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186,0,0,0" Name="calendar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" />
</Grid>
```

Second usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Validator.DownloadView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"                           
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="76" d:DesignWidth="354" Name="Download">     
<Grid>
    <Label Content="States" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,35,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <RadioButton Content="Last 48 hs" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,42,0,0" Name="rdbLast48" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Kind:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,12,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <RadioButton Content="General" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,42,0,0" Name="rdbGeral" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

At MainWindowView.xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="Validator.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:du="clr-namespace:Validator.Download"
        xmlns:resp="clr-namespace:Validator.Resp"                
        Title="Validator" Height="452" Width="668" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
      <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type du:DownloadViewModel}">
            <du:DownloadView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type resp:RespViewModel}">
            <resp:RespView/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>   

        <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PagesName}" 
                   SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentPageName}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,93,0,0" 
                   Name="cmbType"                    
                   Width="187" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22"
                  SelectionChanged="cmbType_SelectionChanged_1" />
         <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" Height="171" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,121,0,0" Name="contentControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="383" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I assigned to the `DataContext` of the MainView, the viewmodel below:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
     #region Fields

    private ICommand _changePageCommand;

    private ViewModelBase _currentPageViewModel;
    private ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> _pagesViewModel = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();        
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _pagesName = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private string _currentPageName = "";

    #endregion

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.LoadUserControls();         

        _pagesName.Add("Download");
        _pagesName.Add("Resp");
    }

    private void LoadUserControls()
    {
        Type type = this.GetType();
        Assembly assembly = type.Assembly;

        UserControl reso = (UserControl)assembly.CreateInstance("Validator.RespView");
        UserControl download = (UserControl)assembly.CreateInstance("Validator.DownloadView");

        _pagesViewModel.Add(new DownloadViewModel());
        _pagesViewModel.Add(new RespViewModel());
    }

    #region Properties / Commands

    public ICommand ChangePageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_changePageCommand == null)
            {
                _changePageCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    p => ChangeViewModel((IPageViewModel)p),
                    p => p is IPageViewModel);
            }

            return _changePageCommand;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> PagesName
    {
        get { return _pagesName; }            
    }

    public string CurrentPageName
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentPageName;
        }
        set
        {                
            if (_currentPageName != value)
            {
                _currentPageName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPageName");
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModelBase CurrentPageViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentPageViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentPageViewModel != value)
            {
                _currentPageViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        int indexCurrentView = _pagesViewModel.IndexOf(CurrentPageViewModel);

        indexCurrentView = (indexCurrentView == (_pagesViewModel.Count - 1)) ? 0 : indexCurrentView + 1;

        CurrentPageViewModel = _pagesViewModel[indexCurrentView];               
    }

    #endregion
}
```

On MainWindowView.xaml.cs, I wrote this event to do the effective change:

```
private void cmbType_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindowViewModel element = this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
    if (element != null)
    {
        ICommand command = element.ChangePageCommand;
        command.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

The app run ok and I inspected the application with WPFInspector and saw that the view changes when the combobox is changed internally, but the ContentControl still empty visually..

Sorry about the amount of code that I posted and my miss of knowledge but I'm working with this a long time and can't solve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Issues:**

- Firstly **don't** ever create View related stuff in the ViewModel (`UserControl`). This is no longer MVVM when you do that.
- Derive ViewModels from `ViewModelBase` and not `ObservableObject` unless you have a compelling reason to not use `ViewModelBase` when using MVVMLight. Keep `ObservableObject` inheritence for Models. Serves as a nice separation between VM's and M's
- Next you do not need to make everything an `ObservableCollection<T>` like your `_pagesViewModel`. You do not have that bound to anything in your View's so it's just a waste. Just keep that as a private List or array. Check what a type actually does in difference to a similar other one.
- Not sure about this one, maybe you pulled this code snippet as a demo, but do not use margins to separate items in a Grid. Your Layout is essentially just 1 Grid cell and the margins have the items not overlap. If you're not aware of that issue, Check into WPF Layout Articles.
- Please don't forget principles of OOP, Encapsulation and sorts when writing a UI app. When having Properties like `CurrentPageViewModel` which you don't intend the View to switch make the property setter `private` to enforce that.
- Don't resort to code-behind in the View too soon. Firstly check if it's **only** a View related concern before doing so. Am talking about your `ComboBox` `SelectionChanged` event handler. Your purpose of that in this demo is to switch the Bound ViewModel which is held in the VM. Hence it's not something that the View is solely responsible for. Thus look for a VM involved approach.

**Solution**:

You can get a working example of your code with the fixes for above from **[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ax35jehysfd7neb/MvvmLight6.rar?dl=0)** and try it out yourself.

Points 1 -> 5 are just basic straightforward changes.

For 6, I've created a `SelectedVMIndex` property in the MainViewModel which is bound to the `SelectedIndex` of the `ComboBox`. Thus when the selected index flips, the property setter after updating itself updates the `CurrentPageViewModel` as well such as

```
public int SelectedVMIndex {
  get {
    return _selectedVMIndex;
  }

  set {
    if (_selectedVMIndex == value) {
      return;
    }

    _selectedVMIndex = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedVMIndex);

    CurrentPageViewModel = _pagesViewModel[_selectedVMIndex];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Viv, it works perfectly! Thank you.
Just one more question, what do you mean with "Firstly don't ever create View related stuff in the ViewModel (UserControl). This is no longer MVVM when you do that." ?

Comment: What I meant by that is "UserControl" is a View Control. Creating that in your ViewModel is not really following MVVM. MVVM disconnects the relation and dependencies between a View and the ViewModel. So you try your best to not create things like UserControl, Button, ComboBox... in your ViewModel. Even things like System.Windows.Visibility are avoided in the VM, you instead use a bool property in the VM and translate it to Visibility in the View using a Converter