# Loading a partial view when selecting a control

Tags: wpf

Sorry for the technically incorrect title, i am aware that partial view is more of an MVC term. However i unsure what the equivalent is in WPF.

I have a large form that the users need to complete. In order to assist them i wanted to split the view in two vertically and show helpful information in the right portion of the screen depending on what field they have selected on the left, or load quick select boxes in the right of the view which will then complete the items on the left.

I've been playing around for a few hours and have managed to split the view with a GridSplitter but from here i'm not sure where to go from here.

Could someone give me a few pointers on what to look at so I can progress. In the MVC world I would have had loaded it through Ajax and it would be done.

**Update**
This question got blocked, honestly im not entirely sure why. The question is valid and seems to be a logical comparison between the two frameworks. Im hoping that the ban is lifted as the answer was exactly what i was looking for and will definitely be helpful to others

Comment: A partial view equivalent would be usercontrol. Host in a contentcontrol if you're switching between different ui elements in the same space. Look up viewmodel first for the usual way to do that. Selection suggests selecteditem of a selector ( listbox, listview, datagrid or combobox). You can bind content of a contentcontrol to a property of selecteditem. Make that object and your viewmodel could expose different viewmodel types via this.

Comment: It's potentially a duplicate question as others have asked how to dynamically/programatically change `UserControls`  (eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107957/how-to-dynamically-change-usercontrol-on-button-click-present-in-the-usercontr) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244240/dynamic-user-control-change-wpf)). I thought your question was specific enough (asking about how to load when focus was changed.) Maybe because you didn't have any code?

Comment: @PeterBoone Quite possible, i had read through multiple posts and tried a good few things but nothing worked as expected. Either way i found your answer very clear and complete. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, and @Andy's comment points you in the correct direction. Here is how I would implement it:

View (`MainView.xaml`):

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewVM />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="Box 1" />
            <TextBox MinWidth="200" Name="TextBox1" GotFocus="TextBox1_GotFocus" />
            <TextBlock Text="Box 2" />
            <TextBox MinWidth="200" Name="TextBox2" GotFocus="TextBox2_GotFocus" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedUserControl}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind (`MainView.xaml.cs`):

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainView : Window
    {
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        // I handle these in the code behind since this is pretty UI dependent.
        private void TextBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((MainViewVM)DataContext).ChangeView(0);
        }

        private void TextBox2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((MainViewVM)DataContext).ChangeView(1);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel `MainViewVM.cs`:

```cs
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    public class MainViewVM : ObservableObject
    {
        private UserControl _SelectedUserControl;
        public UserControl SelectedUserControl
        {
            get => _SelectedUserControl;
            set => Set(ref _SelectedUserControl, value);
        }

        public List<UserControl> ViewOptions { get; set; }

        public MainViewVM()
        {
            ViewOptions = new List<UserControl>()
            {
                new Box1View(),
                new Box2View()
            };
            ChangeView();
        }

        public void ChangeView(int index = 0)
        {
            if (index < ViewOptions.Count && index >= 0)
            {
                SelectedUserControl = ViewOptions[index];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then my 2 `UserControl`s...

`Box1View.xaml`

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp4.Box1View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="Yellow">
        <TextBlock Text="Box 1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`Box2View.xaml`

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp4.Box2View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="Pink">
        <TextBlock Text="Box 2" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here are what the two views look like:

[image: Focus in first box right side is yellow]

[image: focus in second box, right side is pink]

Comment: Also, I'm sure you'll figure this out, but you only need a grid splitter if you want the user to be able to resize the columns (or rows) of the grid. You may or may not need it.

Comment: Thank you  @PeterBoone and Andy for this. Its exactly what i needed